# Copy New Array Value into Old Array in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Let`s say I have got some values in One array, I have created array 2 with same values, and now I want to replace the old array with new array value. (assume I have made some change in the new array value and I want to completely replace the old aaray value with new one).

```
TYPE c_sncode_list      IS VARRAY(10000) OF VARCHAR(1000); 
c_v_sncode              c_sncode_list;
c_v_sncode_update       c_sncode_list;
cou NUMBER := 1;
/* Have c_v_sncode polulated with some value */
FOR J IN c_v_sncode.FIRST .. c_v_sncode.LAST
LOOP
c_v_sncode_update.extend;
c_v_sncode_update(cou) := c_v_sncode(J);
cou := cou + 1;
END LOOP;
c_v_sncode := c_v_sncode_update; -- Is this Correct way?
```

Comment: It's correct way. * But before loop you have to initialize `c_v_sncode_update       := new  c_sncode_list();`

Comment: Yes that was done..but due to some reason I am getting error "ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count " and the line number shown was "c_v_sncode := c_v_sncode_update;" so was confused.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz I have initiazed like         c_v_sncode           :=  c_sncode_list();
  c_v_sncode_update    :=  c_sncode_list(); is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps .

Ur statement is right wrt copying but in for loop u were using c_v_sncode which was not initialized , infact both arrays were not initialised . That will give u "subscript beyond count" error

Also u cant loop and array without having used extend or putting some values in initialization. That will give you numeric or value error

```
            declare
            TYPE c_sncode_list      IS VARRAY(10000) OF VARCHAR(1000);  
            c_v_sncode              c_sncode_list; 
            c_v_sncode_update       c_sncode_list  :=  c_sncode_list(1,2,3,4,5);  -- initialize it and put some values in c_v_sncode_update 
            cou NUMBER := 1;
            /* Have c_v_sncode polulated with some value */
            begin 
            /* print values in c_v_sncode_update*/
            for i in c_v_sncode_update.first .. c_v_sncode_update.last loop
            dbms_output.put_line(c_v_sncode_update(i)) ;
            end loop ;
            c_v_sncode :=  c_v_sncode_update ;

            /* print values in c_v_sncode*/
            for i in c_v_sncode.first .. c_v_sncode.last loop
            dbms_output.put_line(c_v_sncode(i)) ; -- Is this Correct way?
            end loop; 
            end ;
```